# Dashed \xRightarrow

Tags: arrows

I'm looking for a **fat arrow**, where I can write stuff above and below the arrow like with `\xRightarrow[x]{y}`, but I would like the arrow to be *dashed* like with `\dashrightarrow` like so:

[image: Dashed arrow]

I can't seem to find anything like this in any package.

EDIT (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
I would love to have dashed lines on the following arrow:
$\xRightarrow[x]{y}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please  add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Done! Not exactly sure what to put in the MWE though, as I'm looking for a symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get the symbol you want is to take a look at how `mathtools` creates any of those arrows.

For example, `\xRightarrow` is defined as

```
\providecommand*\xRightarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\Rightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
```

`amsmath` defines `\Rightarrowfill@` to produce a `\cleaders` with overlapping boxes.

Since we want space between them rather than overlapping, this approach doesn't quite work. Instead, we can modify the definition to use `\xleaders` and some positive space.

Here's a small suite of dashed, extensible arrows.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\def\dasharrowfill@#1#2#3#4{%
        $\m@th
        \thickmuskip0mu
        \medmuskip\thickmuskip
        \thinmuskip\thickmuskip
        \relax
        #4#1\mkern2mu
        \xleaders\hbox{$#4\mkern2mu#2\mkern2mu$}\hfill
        \mkern2mu
        #3$%
}

\def\dashleftarrowfill@{\dasharrowfill@\leftarrow\relbar\relbar}
\def\dashrightarrowfill@{\dasharrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightarrow}
\def\dashleftrightarrowfill@{\dasharrowfill@\leftarrow\relbar\rightarrow}
\def\dashLeftarrowfill@{\dasharrowfill@\Leftarrow\Relbar\Relbar}
\def\dashRightarrowfill@{\dasharrowfill@\Relbar\Relbar\Rightarrow}
\def\dashLeftrightarrowfill@{\dasharrowfill@\Leftarrow\Relbar\Rightarrow}

\providecommand*\xdashleftarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\dashleftarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\providecommand*\xdashrightarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\dashrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\providecommand*\xdashleftrightarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\dashleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\providecommand*\xdashLeftarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\dashLeftarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\providecommand*\xdashRightarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\dashRightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\providecommand*\xdashLeftrightarrow[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\dashLeftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

You can use them as normal. E.g., `\xdashRightarrow[subscript]{superscript}`.

[image]

The major downside to using `\xleaders` is the space between the boxes that make up the arrows will be spread evenly between them. Thus the dashing is inconsistent.

[image]

One solution would be to constrain the subscripts and superscripts to have an integral number of boxes necessary to make up the `\xleaders`, potentially by producing a modification of `\ext@arrow`.