# Dashed upper rightrightarrows

Tags: arrows, amsfonts

I would like to dash the upper arrow in amsfonts' `\rightrightarrows`. Here is what I had in mind:

[image: 1]]

I've found this similar post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374778/dashed-xrightarrow), but I seem to be unable to even find where amsfonts defines `\rightrightarrows`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a little harder than the question you link to because `\rightrightarrows` is just a single glyph (which is declared in `amssymb.sty` btw). It is not constructed out of two separate arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create this symbol by cutting up and reassembling `\rightrightarrows` using `\clipbox` (from `trimclip.sty`, which is part of [`adjustbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package). 
It doesn't seem very elegant, but it works.
You can tweak the numbers a little if you want longer or shorter dashes or spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,trimclip}

\newcommand*\rightdashedrightarrows{\mathpalette\rightdashedrightarrowsaux\relax}
\newcommand*\rightdashedrightarrowsaux[2]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \clipbox*{0pt          {-\depth} {0.20\width} {\height}}  {$#1\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.20\width} {-\depth} {0.35\width} {.5\height}}{$#1\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.35\width} {-\depth} {0.55\width} {\height}}  {$#1\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.55\width} {-\depth} {0.70\width} {.5\height}}{$#1\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.70\width} {-\depth} {1.00\width} {\height}}  {$#1\rightrightarrows$}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
    A \rightdashedrightarrows B_{C\rightdashedrightarrows D_{E \rightdashedrightarrows F}}
\]

\[
    A \rightrightarrows B_{C\rightrightarrows D_{E \rightrightarrows F}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I'm using [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/156366) to make the symbol also work for different math styles. 
A simpler version of the definition that won't work in sub- or superscripts would be

```
\newcommand*\rightdashedrightarrows{%
  \mathrel{%
    \clipbox*{0pt          {-\depth} {0.20\width} {\height}}  {$\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.20\width} {-\depth} {0.35\width} {.5\height}}{$\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.35\width} {-\depth} {0.55\width} {\height}}  {$\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.55\width} {-\depth} {0.70\width} {.5\height}}{$\rightrightarrows$}%
    \clipbox*{{0.70\width} {-\depth} {1.00\width} {\height}}  {$\rightrightarrows$}%
  }%
}
```